# "Sorting is not stable" when sorting linked list

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, malloc

I am tasked with creating a program that will sort the connection structures. When I submit my program to the test server, it returns that the "sorting is not stable". Don't know what could be wrong?

Sorting is descending if ascending = 0, for other values ascending.
I sort the items alphabetically Case sensitive

Thanks in advance
The entire program including test times https://onecompiler.com/c/3ysjeqn5j
Problem: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stable-and-unstable-sorting-algorithms/

```
TITEM *sortInsert( TITEM *newNode, TITEM *sorted)
{
   // if( sorted || strcmp(sorted->m_Name, newNode->m_Name) == 0 )
   //   return sorted;

    if( !sorted || strcmp(sorted->m_Name, newNode->m_Name) >= 0 )
    {
      newNode->m_Next = sorted;
      sorted = newNode;
    }
    else //Locate the node before the point of insertion
    {
      TITEM *tmp = sorted;
   
      while(tmp->m_Next && strcmp(tmp->m_Next->m_Name, newNode->m_Name) < 0 )
      {
        tmp = tmp->m_Next;
      }
      
      newNode->m_Next = tmp->m_Next;
      tmp->m_Next = newNode;
    }
 

  return sorted;
}

TITEM *sortList ( TITEM *l, int ascending )
{
  TITEM *tmp = l;
  TITEM *sorted = NULL;


  while(tmp)
  {
    TITEM *next = tmp->m_Next;
    sorted = sortInsert(tmp, sorted);
    tmp = next;
  }
  l = sorted;

  if( !ascending )
  {
    l = reverse(l);
  }

  return l;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what it means that it's not stable?

Comment: It's a good thing if you answer my question ;)

Comment: I don't know what to imagine under that phrase, I am not its author. Maybe the sorting is bad?

Comment: A simple "no" had been sufficient. ;) A sorting algorithm is stable if equal elements keep their order.

Comment: Yeah, I googled that too :)

Comment: A stable sort algorithm well suited to linked lists is *merge sort*, fyi.

Comment: @Shawn, merge sort *can be* stable, and that's easy enough to ensure that I don't know why one would intentionally make a different choice, but it doesn't have to be.  Similarly, the OP's insertion sort also could be stable (both directions), and it would not take many changes to make it so.

Answer (score 2):

Compare this, used when sorting ascending ...

> ```
>     if( !sorted || strcmp(sorted->m_Name, newNode->m_Name) >= 0 )
> ```

... to this, used analogously when sorting descending ...

> ```
>     if( !sorted || strcmp(sorted->m_Name, newNode->m_Name) < 0 )
> ```

The former judges the new item to already be ordered correctly if the sorted tail is empty or if the sorted tail's first element compares greater than *or equal to* the new item.  The rest of the code for that sort direction uses the same criterion.  It never reorders an item relative to an equal one, so this sort is stable.

But the latter is not analogous.  It *always* reorders equal items, and therefore is not a stable sort.

The error appears to have been to assume that for all inputs, the correct descending order is the opposite of the correct ascending order.  If a stable sort is required, then that's not true for inputs that contain equal (yet distinguishable) elements.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the sort itself (for example only for ascending) is wrong because it "sorts incorrectly" when the elements are identical (for example).  Am I writing it a bit simplified and is it necessary to use a completely different algorithm?

Comment: Or it doesn't know how to convert it to sorting (if I completely omit the descending option)

Comment: Like descending, I can get rid of it completely by doing a sort and then reverse-rearranging the elements

Comment: A non-stable sort is not "incorrect".  A non-stable sort does fulfill a sorting algorithm's primary requirement, in that the output is indeed sorted.  Many, even most efficient sorting algorithms, I believe, are non-stable.  Stability is an additional requirement, which is either important or not: it's optional.

Comment: You can think of it like this: you and 100 other passengers are waiting to go through security.  You are all on one of three flights: flight 101 leaves at 1:00; flight 202 leaves at 1:15, and flight 303 leaves at 1:30.  There's a long line, and it's almost 1:00.  An agent comes out and says they're going to re-sort the line, so that all of flight 101's passengers will go through security first, then flight 202's, then flight 303's.

Comment: But many of the passengers in line will want to preserve their order in line, relative to the other passengers on their flight.  In other words, they'll want a stable sort.  If they were earlier in line (and therefore able to take better advantage of, say, overhead bin space) they'll want to preserve that advantage.  A non-stable sort wouldn't guarantee that.

Comment: I already understand the problem in principle, but I don't know how to rewrite my program to "stable" and whether it's even possible or if I need to start over with a different algorithm

Comment: @Martin88, as I wrote in this answer, I think your sorting function is *already* stable for the ascending direction.  So no, you do not need to choose a different algorithm (not for stability, at least).  You *do* need to understand your own code well enough to recognize where the descending sort it will reorder nodes with equal values, and make it stop doing that.  I've already pointed you at one of the problem areas.