# C - Sort linked list by string

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I have a program that sorts a linked list by string (`m_Name` values). The problem is that the program is unstable (I mean this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stable-and-unstable-sorting-algorithms/ ).

Is there any way to fix my code to make the sort stable or should I create some other algorithm. Alternatively, do you know what kind of algorithm would be appropriate if I can't use any library for `qsort` etc.

All program https://onecompiler.com/c/3ysjeqn5j

Or if there is any material I can study to create a stable sort algorithm for linked list, please tell me.

```
TITEM *sortInsert(TITEM *newNode, TITEM *sorted) {
    //if (sorted || strcmp(sorted->m_Name, newNode->m_Name) == 0)
    //    return sorted;

    if (!sorted || strcmp(sorted->m_Name, newNode->m_Name) >= 0) {
        newNode->m_Next = sorted;
        sorted = newNode;
    } else { //Locate the node before the point of insertion
        TITEM *tmp = sorted;
   
        while (tmp->m_Next && strcmp(tmp->m_Next->m_Name, newNode->m_Name) < 0) {
            tmp = tmp->m_Next;
        }
      
        newNode->m_Next = tmp->m_Next;
        tmp->m_Next = newNode;
    }
    return sorted;
}

TITEM *sortList(TITEM *l, int ascending) {
    TITEM *tmp = l;
    TITEM *sorted = NULL;

    while (tmp) {
        TITEM *next = tmp->m_Next;
        sorted = sortInsert(tmp, sorted);
        tmp = next;
    }
    l = sorted;

    if (!ascending) {
        l = reverse(l);
    }

    return l;
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about stable sort?  In general we are not going to follow external links so you want to make sure your question is self-contained.

Comment: Did the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74878833#74879177) at [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74878833) not help?

Comment: @AllanWind Yes, I am talking about stable sort, to clarify the problem I have attached a link where the problem is explained

Comment: @SteveSummit no, It's a slightly different question

Comment: Okay, sorry, I thought there was an important hint there about `<` versus `<=`, but maybe not.

Comment: @SteveSummit that's not the source of the error (or it's not the only one, I already tried that)

Comment: Or if there is any material I can study to create a stable sort algorithm for linked list, please write it to me

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the instability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your approach:

- you are inserting the elements from the list one at a time into the sorted list, hence if the element is identical to some already in the sorted list, it should be inserted **after** the duplicates in order to stay in the same relative order. You must change the comparison operators to `>` and `<=` respectively.
- you cannot handle descending order by reversing the list as the duplicate elements are going to appear in reverse order too. A simple solution is passing the sort direction and multiplying the return value of `strcmp()` by either `1` or `-1` depending on the direction. The duplicates will be kept in the original relative order as `strcmp` returns `0` for them in both directions.

Here is a modified version:

```
// insert a node according to sorting direction
TITEM *sortInsert(TITEM *newNode, TITEM *sorted, int dir) {
    if (!sorted || strcmp(sorted->m_Name, newNode->m_Name) * dir > 0) {
        newNode->m_Next = sorted;
        sorted = newNode;
    } else { //Locate the node before the point of insertion
        TITEM *tmp = sorted;
   
        while (tmp->m_Next && strcmp(tmp->m_Next->m_Name, newNode->m_Name) * dir <= 0) {
            tmp = tmp->m_Next;
        }
        newNode->m_Next = tmp->m_Next;
        tmp->m_Next = newNode;
    }
    return sorted;
}

TITEM *sortList(TITEM *l, int ascending) {
    int dir = ascending ? 1 : -1;
    TITEM *tmp = l;
    TITEM *sorted = NULL;

    while (tmp) {
        TITEM *next = tmp->m_Next;
        sorted = sortInsert(tmp, sorted, dir);
        tmp = next;
    }
    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: This approach should be adequate on most systems, yet I expect language lawyers to point a remote possibility for undefined behavior :)

Comment: That line int dir = ascending ? 1 : -1; I had it in the original program, but I removed it because I assumed that it would work poorly due to other things.

I didn't realize that with comparing >=  (<=)and > at all, I'm probably overworked. Thank you very much :)